# How to see XML comments of the code from Reflector

Tags: .net, reflector, xml-comments

I prefer to browse the assemblies using reflector even though i have source code with me specially in case when i move to new project.
But I feel it would be nice if i could see the XML comments of the source code in reflector.

Is any addin which would do that?

Thanks In advance,
Uday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML comments are not compiled into assembly - they go into separate XML file. If it is your assembly, or XML file is shipped with the assembly you're trying to analyze, then Reflector will pick them up automatically. If not - you are out of options, sorry...

Edit: Anyway, those comments won't be displayed alongside your code - you'll see them below the disassembly window, documentation-style formatted.

Edit2: It appears that you can display your XML comments inline if you want to - there is an option for that in settings dialog. Didn't know that! :)

Comment: Thanks Michal, as you told i didnt have xml file along with the assembly.

Comment: Then, if you have source code, you can do as follows:

- open the code in Visual Studio
- go into project Properties, tab Build, and check XML Documentation File option
- rebuild

Now you should have your XML comments file for use with Resharper.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=8630