# C# .NET framework, can't find comment in the .dll class

Tags: c#, siemens

In the video Siemens posted [online](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/tecnomatix/part-2-how-digital-twins-help-scale-up-industrial-robotics-ai/), I saw a code. This code is part of the EngineeringInternalExtension.dll library. Please find the library [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Si3LM7ai4H0rgldyVcdyZX6S2RfbvMQz?usp=sharing).

[info from internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmTOK.png)

They always have a comment for each method. This is really helpful for me to understand the API. But in my current code, please find it below, I found no comment at all. I don't know why this happens, I think it might be that I use the wrong reference, could you please help me?

[my info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUs1u.png)

Comment: Not sure what the question is here, you have two screenshots of two different classes. Can you explain what the question is with more details?

Comment: Since both screenshots shows disassembled versions of .dll files, could it be that you're missing the .XML file that contains the documentation?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have the related `EngineeringInternalExtension.xml` file.

Comments should be stored there.

Comment: I can't find the related EngineeringInternalExtension.xml file. Can I open the .dll file to see what is inside?

Comment: '/// comments' are not in the assembly file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202522/how-can-the-net-source-code-xml-comments-be-persisted-in-the-assembly-metadata

Comment: Thanks a lot, should the XML file always have the same name as the .dll file? Because I can't find EngineeringInternalExtension.xml on my computer, maybe it has a different name. I can find EngineeringInternalExtension.pdb on my computer

Comment: Yes. File '.pdb' contains debug symbols, it doesn't contain comments.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to contact the developer of this .dll file to ask for a . XML file. Do you know any other approaches?

Comment: IMO, no way ...

Comment: I got the .xml file, and it works for me now. Thanks a lot!